# Publish to AGOL with Editing Enabled (and other Operations and Properties) using ArcPy (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-online, publishing

I have a script that accesses an APRX and publishes a feature service to AGOL. I cannot figure out how to enable editing in the script or any other of the Operations and Properties in the screenshot below (with exception of the Export Data which is a property of getWebLayerSharingDraft)

[image: default properties]

Is there a way to Enable editing, choose one of the radio buttons, Enable Sync, and check on or off the Properties such as Preserve editor tracking info using ArcPy? Essentially I want the script to perform enable the below options.

[image: wanted properties via arcpy]

I am using ArcGIS Pro version 2.7 and the standard install of python that comes with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using the arcgis API for Online/Enterprise that can update the setting after the item has been published.

```
import json
from arcgis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

conn = GIS("home")

item = conn.content.get('feature servide id')

with open(r"filepath\to\json_file.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

layer = FeatureLayer(item.url)
layer.manager.update_definition(data)
```

The JSON file contains the below.

```
{
    "hasStaticData": false,
    "capabilities": "Create,Query,Update,Editing,Extract,Sync,ChangeTracking",
    "editorTrackingInfo": {
        "enableEditorTracking": true,
        "enableOwnershipAccessControl": false,
        "allowOthersToQuery": true,
        "allowOthersToUpdate": true,
        "allowOthersToDelete": true,
        "allowAnonymousToQuery": true,
        "allowAnonymousToUpdate": true,
        "allowAnonymousToDelete": true
  }
}
```

Results in the below capabilities being set on the feature service.

[image: Updated Feature Service Capabilities]

Comment: Your original question mentioned "Preserve Editor Tracking Info." There are additional parameters you can use to control that: `{"editorTrackingInfo" : {"enableEditorTracking":'true', "preserveEditUsersAndTimestamps":'true'}}` See [Publishing to AGOL overwrites editor tracking data](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/publishing-to-agol-overwrites-editor-tracking-data/m-p/197387#M9722) for more info.